# Create a block with sorting in drop down

Tags: blocks

Using Organic group module, In the block I want to create sort dropdown as shown in image. Which will allow to sort the data according to various parameters like date, tag, group etc.

How can I achieve it programmatically.

[image: dropdown image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use table display to manage the listing of all the posts.
Now to filter/sort the data you can user [ctools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) jump menu. Using [Ctools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) jump menu you can create various menu items for different sorting type.

To see the example of Ctools jump menu see the **ctools_ajax_sample** module which comes with Ctools module package.